# Making python dictionary from an excel table

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am a beginner to python dictionary use. It is almost always pointed out that they are a good alternative to the use of dynamic lists or multi-dimensional arrays. My idea is to prepare a master dictionary by combining 3 dictionaries having similar keys. The difficulty is when reading the data from an excel sheet, based on some comparisons.

```
+------+------------+----------+----------+
| keys |    val1    |   val2   |   val3   |
+------+------------+----------+----------+
|  100 | football   |  apple   | pencil   |
|  200 | baseball   | <NoVal2> | pen      |
|  100 | basketball | <NoVal2> | <NoVal3> |
|  100 | rugby      | orange   | <NoVal3> |
|    0 | cricket    | grapes   | <NoVal3> |
|  100 | hockey     | lemon    | <NoVal3> |
|  200 | tennis     | <NoVal2> | desk     |
+------+------------+----------+----------+
```

I wish to create a master dictionary with ranks 0, 100, and 200 in the following format:

```
0:      [grapes]
100:    [pencil, basketball, orange, lemon]
200:    [pen, desk]
```

Where val3 has highest rank, follwed by val2 and val1. This means that when there is an entry  in the column under val3, val2 is considered. And when  is detected under column val2, val1 is considered (least priority).

```
import xlrd

workbook_read = xlrd.open_workbook('random_data.xlsx')
sheets = workbook_read.sheets()
worksheet = sheets[0]

master_keys = []

col = 0
for row in range(worksheet.nrows):
    if row > 0:
        master_keys.append(str(worksheet.cell_value(row, col)))

master_keys = list(set(master_keys))

dict_val1 = {}
dict_val2 = {}
dict_val3 = {}


for row in range(worksheet.nrows):
    if str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 3)) == "<NoVal3>":
        if str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 2)) == "<NoVal2>":
            key = '{}'.format(str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 0)))
            dict_val1.update({key:str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 1))})   # Val1
        else:
            key = '{}'.format(str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 0)))
            dict_val2.update({key:str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 2))})   # Val2
            print(dict_val2)
    else: 
        if row is not 0:
            key = '{}'.format(str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 0)))
            dict_val3.update({key:str(worksheet.cell_value(row, 3))})   # Val3
```

For example, the print result I get is:

```
 - {'100.0': 'orange'} 
 - {'100.0': 'orange', '0.0': 'grapes'}
 - {'100.0': 'lemon', '0.0': 'grapes'}
```

If I could get the 'lemon' to be updated as a list to '100', I may get the required component dictionary as a result. I am unsure about using the update function in the python dictionary during loop calls. Or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: so for entries with the same key, values will just be appended?

Comment: yes. exactly. I have updated the question with a bit more of my attempted code.

Comment: for key = 100, should it be [pencil, apple, lemon, ...]?

Comment: If you mean what I wish my final result was, then it is 100: [pencil, basketball, orange, lemon]. The attempted part are components of it. as you can see 'orange' and 'lemon' are part of the final values of key '100'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use nested loops here. The outer loop will iterate over rows, and append a new value for each row, while the inner loop will iterate on the 3 possible values keeping the best one.

```
master_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    best = None
    for col in range(1, 4):
        if not str(worksheet.cell(row, col).value).startswith("<NoVal"):
            best = worksheet.cell(row, col).value
    master_dict[str(worksheet.cell(row, 0).value)].append(best)
```

Comment: This code works neatly except that my excel sheet also had other columns in between. This is the reason why I had to specify the column numbers during comparison statements. Now, I specified the exact column field to compare using an if statement inside the loop and it works, thank you.